# Why does PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX generates 11.955 font size for 12pt documentclass option?

Tags: pdf, fontsize

I am currently working on post-processing PDFs that are generated from either `pdflatex` or `xelatex` with the **12pt** documentclass option.  Since I am looking at the uncompressed PDF sources, I noticed that the PDF command **Tf** to select the font specifies a font size of 11.955 instead of 12.  I am curious: does anyone here know why?

Minimal example for XeLaTex:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
Why is this font size 11.955 in PDF?
\end{document}
```

but typeset with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V4 -z0" <FILE>` to obtain uncompressed PDF output.  Then, looking at the .pdf file, the first object is the stream:

```
stream
 q 1 0 0 1 72 720 cm BT /F1 11.955 Tf 56.41 -65.75 Td[(Wh)26(y)-325(is)-326(this)-327(fon)26(t)-325(size)-326(11.955)-327(in)-326(PDF?)]TJ 173.79 -564.39 Td[(1)]TJ ET Q

endstream
```

and you can see `/F1 11.955 Tf` to select the indirect font object called `/F1` with size 11.955.  The same effect if you use `pdflatex`, for example with this input:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0

\begin{document}
Why is this font size 11.955 in PDF?
\end{document}
```

My `pdflatex` (from Mac TexLive 2014) then generates:

```
stream
BT
/F15 11.9552 Tf 128.413 654.247 Td [(Wh)27(y)-326(is)-327(this)-326(fon)27(t)-326(size)-326(11.955)-327(in)-326(PDF?)]TJ 173.786 -564.384 Td [(1)]TJ
ET

endstream
```

with a font size of 11.9552.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's due to the different idea that `pdf` and `LaTeX` have of what's a point:

- A `LaTeX` point is 1/72.27 inch - known in `LaTeX` as `pt`
- A `pdf` point is exactly 1/72 inch - known in `LaTeX` as `bp` (big point)

Thus the ration between the two is 1.00375 - which is also the ratio 12/11.955. In fact the 11.955 are rounded from 11.9̅5̅5̅1̅6̅8̅1̅1̅.

See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200954/5763) and  [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29).