# Is the "legalpaper" paper size larger than the standard?

Tags: paper-size

I have a document that I've set with `\documentclass[legalpaper]`, expecting it to produce a PDF that's the standard 8.5" x 14" size. When I go to print the PDF, I've found that it's actually about an inch larger than 14". I have to shrink the document to fit on the page in order to get it to print on an actual, standard, American 8.5" x 14" piece of legal paper. I've tried using `legal` instead of `legalpaper`, but it seems that `legal` produces a document that's significantly smaller than actual legal paper. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt,legalpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin={50px,25px}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
   \lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case you are not loading package `geometry` (`paper=legalpaper`), the documentclass sets the paper size. Can you tell us that, most preferrably in form of a minimal working example?

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/4uuSKRm2. I did invoke `geometry` after `documentclass`, but I use it to set the margins, not the paper size.

Comment: Try to do it via geometry. But i guess it is a printer issue. `letterpaper` is the default for article, i guess people would have noticed if something is wrong there.

Comment: I tried via geometry too, and it produced the same thing. I'm think you're right, and that this is a printer driver error or an issue with the PDF viewer I'm using. I apologize.

Comment: There sometimes is a feature *fit to page* (or something alike). Try to *not use* that.

Comment: Using Adobe PDF Reader, the only way I could get the document to fit on the page properly was to use the "Fit" option. If I use the "Actual Size" option, it cuts off like this: http://i.imgur.com/HiCNLW4.jpg. The PDF page size is 8.5x14, and the physical paper is the same. This is definitely starting to seem like some sort of driver/software error that I need to fix, but I'm not sure what to look for at this point. I've tried looking for a number of things and haven't had any luck.

Comment: Nice picture ;-) Have you tried another reader/viewer? I heard [Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) is quite good.

Comment: seeing that you have rather small margins, I would guess the problem is that paper sizes match, but the area your printer is actually able to print on is smaller than the area you have text on - i.e. your margins (in the pdf) are smaller than the minimum margins the printer produces.

Comment: Thanks! Coincidentally, I also tried Sumatra. I'm having the same error with that one, also.

Comment: Ahhh, greyshade, I think you might be right. I'm going to look in to that right now, and will report back.

Comment: You were right, greyshade. It looks like it was a mistake to be frugal when I bought this printer! ;)

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley *Never* use `px` as a unit of measure.

Comment: @egreg, I usually don't, but using it was the only way I was able to get the document to fit the way I wanted. Is there another unit of measure I should have used that is as precise? (I'm still very new to LaTeX)

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley Points (`pt`) would be the preferred way to go in most cases.. see [here for a discussion about points](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200882/why-does-pdflatex-and-xelatex-generates-11-955-font-size-for-12pt-documentclass/200885#200885)

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley The default value is `1px=1bp` (and `72bp=1in`). But `px` can be set on a document basis, so its value is not predictable.

Comment: Ah cool, good to know. I'll use `bp` instead!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to the printer driver